# Machine size recommendation for fast syncing on Ropsten?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I am planning on syncing my geth node with Ropsten using Ubuntu on AWS. From my pains I've experienced so far I'm uncovering that I'll need :
`8 cores, 64GB RAM, 100Mbps Internet connection, 300GB SSD drive` and that I should run a cache size `--cache=8192`

Let me know if that seems correct or please let me know what is minimum to get a full sync using fast mode.

It took me 3 days to get all the blocks minus the last 65 of them using `Ubuntu 16, 1gb ram, 2 gb swap file, 32gb drive, Download: 302.30 Mbit/s, Upload: 232.94 Mbit/s`

Answer (score 3):

I am using standard $10 DigitalOcean machine `2 GB memory, 1 vCPU core, 50 GB SSD, 2 TB transfer`. Only thing I fixed is adding at least 100 Gb storage. Ropsten network was synced in 20-24 hours if `fast` mode.

Comment: thats actually great news, mine is still not synced and is going on day 4. Would you mind sharing your launch commands? I'm using `geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --ipcpath /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=2048 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --port "30303" --networkid 3`

Comment: First of all I cleaned up database from past experiments and used this command in supervisord config: `command=geth --testnet --networkid=3 --fast --port 30303 --datadir=/var/lib/ethereum/ropsten --rpc --rpcport=18545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner"`

Comment: I'm so nervous about using `removeDB` because it took me so many days to get here.

Comment: @JJacquet I suppose you can just move database to another folder.